# PJSIP + FFMPEG build error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, pjsip

I'm trying to build PJSIP with FFMPEG for Android.
For building FFMPEG with rtmp and openssl, I use this project:
https://github.com/cine-io/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp

and it compiles pretty well.

Then I'm compiling pjsip 2.6 with ffmpeg. Here is the part from my **build** file:

```
    APP_PLATFORM=android-${TARGET_ANDROID_API} NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 TARGET_ABI=$arch ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags \
                                     --with-ssl="${OPENSSL_BUILD_OUT_PATH}/libs/${arch}" \
                                     --with-ffmpeg="${BASE_DIR}/ffmpeg-output"
                                     >>"${FINAL_BUILD_LOGS}/${arch}.log" 2>&1
```

My target ABI is **armeabi**.

**Also, i've defined these two flags:**

#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1

#define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG 1

But the build failed with a bunch of these two errors:

error: cannot find -lbz2

error: cannot find -lasound

A have libasound2-dev and bzip2 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM.

Before that, I've successfully made pjsip builds with OpenH264 with no errors like this.

Is there any way to tell linker(or whatever it is) how to find those packages?

Comment: Please add the two libraries into your pjsip project. Then link the libraries using makefile called build.mak.in on $(PJ_DIR) Path

Comment: @NandhaKumar What do you mean by 'add two libraries into your project'? I need to copy them manually? For the libasound2-dev this is gonna be libasound.so, am I right? But what I need to copy to project from bzip2? Also idk destination folder, is this a third_party folder? Maybe you have the link on how to link the files - I not very good at compiling libs at all, sorry for a lot of questions btw.

Comment: error occured was cannot find library files -lbz2 and -lasound. So clearly it shows that, the libraries are not linked with your pjsip project. put those libraries into your project and directly link those libraries using makefile.

Comment: @NandhaKumar Could you be so patient and describe me what to do? I've got **libasound.so**, **libasound.so.2** and **libasound.so.2.0.0** at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder and **libbz2.so.1.0** and **libbz2.so.1.0.6** I've just compiled. Where do I need to put this files? Also, could you give me at least the link from what I can understand, what changes I need to make in makefile - I'm completely don't know how to do it.

Comment: add those libraries into $(PJ_DIR)/third_party/lib/ path. link those libraries into your project using build.mak.in file. Then try building the project

Comment: @NandhaKumar I've place libs i mentioned above in the $(PJ_DIR)/third_party/lib/ path. To link them, I wrote these lines in build.mak.in file like this: APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_FILES += $(PJ_DIR)/third_party/lib/libasound.so
and got these errors with warning -->            
error: cannot find -lbz2
warning: skipping incompatible /tmp/pjsip/third_party/lib/libasound.so while searching for asound
error: cannot find -lasound

Comment: @NandhaKumar I understand what I'm doing wrong: I need .a libraries instead of .so - doing that with bzip2 and error dissapears. But same stuff(compining libasound.a, copying to pjsip thrid party libs dir and changing build.mak.in file) doesn't help - i still have "error: cannot find -lasound". Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to add additional line for linking library. check that build.mak.in file, like this APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIBS += -lsound , you also want to add like above command

Comment: @NandhaKumar Added APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_FILES += $(PJ_DIR)/third_party/lib/libasound.a
APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIBS += -lsound gives me the same resull (also tried with -lasound) Maybe I need some another libasound.a?

Comment: still showing same error? which means it can't find libasound library. Linker error. you have libasound library file right? check its architecture using lipo -info libasound.a . Make sure it has architecture what you are building for your app.

Comment: @NandhaKumar I've just added libasound.a to ANDROID_NDK path and error dissappears! Mr. Kumar, thank you for your patience!

Comment: great one. post your answer for this question. it helps someone !

Answer (score 1):

Solve that problem (thx @NandhaKumar) by compiling .a libs for each library above and adding them to pjsip library path:

- Build .a libs.
- Copy libs to {PJPROJECT}/third_party/lib/ folder.
- Go to the build.mak.in file in your PJSIP project folder.
- Add the following lines:

APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_FILES += $(PJ_DIR)/third_party/lib/libbz2.a
APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_FILES += $(PJ_DIR)/third_party/lib/libasound.a

- In my case (and I still don't know why) second line and defining another line
  (APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIBS += -lsound or APP_THIRD_PARTY_LIBS += -lasound) doesn't help, so I just copied this library into the android_ndk folder:

android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libasound.a

Comment: did you try without integrating library with pjsip and changes in build.mak.in ?  Instead just add library into android ndk path and build pjsip, check for errors. i think that itself it includes library. just check!

Comment: I've done it like you said. Everything works! Thank again, mr. @NandhaKumar